# Syrian citizen with valid Schengen visa and KSA residency - Turkish visa needed?

Tags: visas, schengen, turkey, saudi-arabia, syrian-citizens

I'm a Syrian citizen, travelling from Paris to Turkey and Saudi Arabia. Do I need a Turkish visa? I have valid residency in Saudi Arabia and a Schengen visa.

Comment: Do you intend to visit Turkey or do you just have a layover?